# Entity Framework select most recent record for each type of record

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have a table called values that looks like this:

```
+-------+------------+-----------+----------+
|Id     |DateTime    |SensorId   |Value     |
+-------+------------+-----------+----------+
```

SensorId is a foreign key to a table of the sensor details. There will be 10m+ records in this values table.

I can run this sql command to return the most recent record for each SensorId and it runs in about 0.3 seconds.

```
SELECT a.*
    FROM Values as a
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT SensorId, MAX(ID) maxId 
        FROM Values
        GROUP BY SensorId
    ) b ON a.SensorId = b.SensorId 
        AND a.Id = b.maxId
ORDER BY a.SensorId ASC
```

How can I achieve the same output with entity framework in a c# application while maintaining (or improving) the performance?

Comment: make it into a view, add the view to EF.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With LINQ to Entities and lambdas you can do it like this:

```
dataContext.Values.GroupBy(p => p.SensorId)
     .Select(p => p.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Id == p.Max(m => m.Id)))  
     .OrderBy(p => p.SensorId).ToList()
```

where dataContext is your instance of `ObjectContext` class. `ToList()` compiles the query.

Comment: This works but takes 6 seconds to run. I need it to be faster.

Answer (score 1):

1. I guess it would not be possible reach better performance than pure SQl query because by using EF you are adding abstraction layer to the process.
2. EF is usually very slow with GroupBy command.  I suggest try sql query in EF directly
   (this code is for **EF Core**)

```
context.Values.FromSqlRaw<Values>("SELECT a.*
    FROM Values as a
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT SensorId, MAX(ID) maxId 
        FROM Values
        GROUP BY SensorId
    ) b ON a.SensorId = b.SensorId 
        AND a.Id = b.maxId
ORDER BY a.SensorId ASC").ToList<Values>();
```

FromSqlRaw is faster than a normal Linq Query. for EF you can try `context.ExecuteQuery<Values>` by the same way.